# Partial effect of numerical variable for a fixed level of categorical variable in regression

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, regression-coefficients

I have a regression model (in R) as follows:

`lm(price ~ time + color + brand)`

where, *price* be the second hand price of sth (numerical), *time* be number of years since produced (numerical), *color* be color of it with 10 different levels (categorical), and *brand* be brand of it with 5 different levels (categorical).

When I run this regression, I find a significant negative coefficient for *time*, so price decreases by time, which is expected based on domain. Some colors turns out to be significant, and some are not.

My question is, how can I measure **change of price over time** for **a particular color**? For instance, maybe *price* does not significantly change with *time* when *color* is black, but it decreases significantly when *color* is yellow.

Do I need to run 10 different regressions (using all brands & time in regression), as there are 10 different colors? Or, is there any shorter way in statistics (in R)?

**Edit**

`reg1<-lm(price ~ time + color + brand)`

time is significant (with negative coefficient), all colors are insignificant (9 colors excluding reference)

`anova(reg1)`
color is significant (??)

Now regression with interactions
`reg2<-lm(price ~ time + color + brand + time*color)`

Result: time is insignificant, some colors are significant, some are not, all interactions are insignificant

`anova(reg2)`

Result: time is significant, color is significant, interaction is significant

Comment: You would do this with an interaction, via the command `lm(price ~ time*color + brand)`. Be sure to carefully interpret the time slopes as relative to the reference color.

Comment: Thanks Ben!
I did that, and **none** of time:color interaction turns out to be significant (with respect to reference color). On the other hand, when I call anova() function for that regression, time:color interaction seems very significant. Do you have any idea?

Comment: could you show the command and output, possibly in your question?

Comment: just did. two regressions, without (reg1) and with(reg2) interactions

Comment: Thanks, could you include the output as well?

Comment: I already added the summary of the results, which are significant and which are not. I cannot add the real results as the real problem has much more variables, and results for two regressions may take so much space. I just simplified the problem above.